# What are the features and functions of Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need some detailed info of Magento Cloud and its features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/bk-cloud.html), Magento Cloud is a managed and automated high-availability hosting platform for Magento specifically created and hosted on the Cloud. This version combines Magento Commerce, Cloud hosting, with a few differences and added features including Git integration and three key environments for development, staging, and live production.

In Magento cloud you can access your Magento development and deployment through a UI console or CLI. Your servers are within reach from development to production in the Amazon Web Services (AWS) cloud.

It has three environments Integration (developer environment), Staging and Production.

It includes eight active environments for development and integration. Additional active environments are available at additional cost. Each active environment includes a database, environment variables, and configurations.

You have an unlimited number of inactive Git branches and you can add fully managed services like MySQL, Elasticsearch, Redis, RabbitMQ, and so on, without requiring external add-ons. It uses a robust Composer build process and you can increase the amount of memory and CPU as needed.